# Pass request uri to proxy as query param Nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to pass a url like a query param to a proxy if the user agent is a crawler. I have:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|Facebot|developers\.google\.com") {

 // Get the request Url, such as http://my-page.com/foo/bar/
 // pass to the proxy as query param such as: http://localhost:3030?page=http://my-page.com/foo/bar/:    

}
```

Comment: What does your `server` block look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky. I think that you don't want to generate HTTP 301 or 302 redirects which can be done easily with this config:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|Facebot|developers\.google\.com) {
    return 301 http://localhost:3000?page=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

but want a "transparent" proxying, when crawlers does not see a redirect but gets a normal (HTTP 200 OK) response instead.

We can't use [`proxy_set_header`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) directive inside an `if` block, and without it we cannot achieve a "transparent" proxying, but we can use the following workaround:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* googlebot|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|Facebot|developers\.google\.com) {
    set $args page=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
    rewrite (.*) /passtoproxy$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/passtoproxy/.* {
    proxy_set_header Host localhost;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; # optional, if needed
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000?$args;
}
```

In this example a virtual `/passtoproxy` location is defined (of course, this path must not exist within your real site), but you can choose something more unique, like randomly generated string of enough length.

If you want to pass a request to a different proxy, for example `my-proxy.com`, you must also change first `proxy_set_header` directive to `proxy_set_header Host my-proxy.com;`.

**Update**

You may need to add a [`resolver`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) directive to your `server` block in order to get this to work.

For testing you can add "curl" to the list of robots and check how this config works with the `curl` utility.